# Django, my for loop is not showing in include template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.1

Hello I am a beginner with Django and Python. I am currently in my project using a for loop in the template but it does not show anything. Could someone help me and explain me what I am doing wrong?

**models.py**

```
class ImageCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=120)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "image categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import ImageCategory

def HomeView(request):
template = loader.get_template('editor.html')

return HttpResponse(template.render())


def LibraryOverviewView(request):  
    return render(request, 'library_overview.html', {'image_categories': ImageCategory.objects.all()})
```

So I put the category information in the libraryOverView, but the editor.html is using HomeView. **library_overview.html** is included in another html called **editor.html**

**editor.html**

```
section class="toolbox document-tools">
              <ul>
                <li class="tb-title">Document</li>
                <!-- uncomment to see all available styles -->
                <!--
                <li class="tb-btn tb-btn-big tb-btn-disabled">Preview</li>
                -->
                <li class="tb-btn tb-btn-big" id="btn-export">Export</li>
                <li class="tb-btn tb-btn-big tb-btn-action">Save</li>
              </ul>
            </section>

          </span>

          {% include 'library_overview.html' %}

          {% include 'library_categories/colorful_images.html' %}

          {% include 'library_categories/colorful_images_categories/blue_images.html' %}

        </span>
```

**library_overview.html**

```
{% for category in image_categories %}
     <a class="tb-btn tb-btn-label tb-btn-radio no-bg slide-forward">-> {{ category.name }}</a>
 {% empty %}
     <p> There are no Categories yet </p>
 {% endfor %}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [url(r'^library_overview/', views.LibraryOverviewView, 
    name='LibraryOverviewView'),
```

Comment: Including a template does *not* somehow run another view.

Comment: @Alasdair I`m sorry, the question was wrong but I changed it. And reading my own question then, made me realize I put the information in the wrong view. But I fixed it now.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem :)

Comment: Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The editor.html is using the HomeView, and not LibraryOverviewView. But the html for libraryOverviewView was included inside editor.html, thus still using the HomeView. Moving the information from LibraryOverView to HomeView worked.